# Do you have to do the events to get through the game?

Tags: prototype

There are many events in the game that give you EP that you can use to enhance your characters. Is it necessary to do them or can you get through the game (in terms of combat abilities and survival) without them just fine?

I ask because I have no interest in spending more time with Prototype 1 than necessary to understand the story and events to be able to move on to the second title of the game.

Comment: While I didn't watch it, Prototype 2 has an option in the menu to recap the events of Prototype 1. Since the events aren't overly complex, you really shouldn't feel obligated to go through 1 just to understand the story.

Comment: I bought both because I wanted to play the first one - just not as extensivly. It is not like I am not enjoying it^^ if it sounds like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can complete the game without completing a single side event, I did so myself. They only give extra EP but you can get enough EP from other missions and collectibles.

I do recommend you do the optional infiltration missions because these give unique and useful abilities, and usually don't take more than a few minutes each.